# Convert unsigned char* to std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>>

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I'm trying to change a variable of type `unsigned char*` to `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>>` for memory management. The thing is, this code was written by a coworker who left several years ago, and I'm not so sure how to manage the change in some methods since I'm not familiar with them. Currently, I'm stuck with this function to get the buffer of an image from the class `BaseImage`.

```
const unsigned char* BaseImage::getConstBuffer() const
{
    if(m_bufferSize == 0) return 0;
    else return m_bufferData + m_headerSize;
}
```

With:

```
unsigned int m_bufferSize;
unsigned short m_headerSize;
unsigned char* m_bufferData = new unsigned char[(unsigned) m_headerSize + m_bufferSize];
```

I'm not sure to understand why we are adding `m_bufferData` to `m_headerSize`, and what would be the proper way to change it after the conversion. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: First of all, you almost *never* need a pointer to a container. What's the reason you have it? Secondly, pointers works similarly to iterators (or rather, iterators were designed to kind of work like pointers), and `std::vector` have a [constructor overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes an iterator pair.

Comment: Good question, I never met the developer who wrote this code, so I don't know why he made this choice.

Comment: @BoolMimi *You* are the one making this choice. The other commenter is telling you that your proposed change makes no sense.

Comment: Most records have (usually fixed length A) header section for some meta-data about the kind of and amount of data in record followed by (usually variable length B) data section. To get whole record length in bytes one has to sum those two lengths A and B up. I suspect something like that is going on in code you show.

Comment: I could understand the intention to turn `unsigned char* m_bufferData = new unsigned char[(unsigned) m_headerSize + m_bufferSize];` into `std::vector<unsigned char> m_bufferData{ m_headerSize + m_bufferSize };`. The `std::shared_ptr` doesn't make sense. Please, note that the `unsigned char*` represents a dynamic array in this case. (This is how it was done in C.) With `std::vector`, it vanishes under the hood which is actually one of its advantages. Just returning `m_bufferData` as `const std::vector<unsigned char>&` in your getter is actually some kind of smart-pointing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry, I misunderstood. I'm trying to fix memory leaks coming from m_bufferData. I thought using a shared pointer would help with that, and since shared_ptr could not be used to manage dynamically allocated arrays with C++-11, I thought I should replace it with a vector.

Comment: @BoolMimi `std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]>` exists in C++11 (it lacks `operator[]` until 17)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat the original method is returning only part of the allocated `unsigned char[]` so you can't return `vector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really need* the callers of this function to share ownership of the return value, then you can use `std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]>`. Much more likely, callers only get to observe the pointed to data, and don't need to own it. In that case, you can use `std::vector<unsigned char>` as the data member, and return a span type ([std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) is C++20, [gsl::span](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) requires C++14 but could be adapted to C++11)

```
class BaseImage
{
    unsigned short m_headerSize;
    std::vector<unsigned char> m_bufferData;
public:
    BaseImage(size_t bufferSize, unsigned short headerSize) : m_headerSize(headerSize), m_bufferData(bufferSize + headerSize) {}

    span<const unsigned char> BaseImage::getConstBuffer() const
    {
        return { m_bufferData.data() + m_headerSize, m_bufferData.size() - m_headerSize };
    }
};
```

Comment: `span` is of course more fancy. Alternatively, a `std::vector<unsigned char> m_bufferData` could be used without an API break: `if (m_bufferData.size() <= m_headerSize) return nullptr; else return &m_bufferData[m_headerSize];` (with the drawback that the size of the returned array is not included).

Comment: I'd use `m_bufferData.data() + m_headerSize`, but yes

Comment: Thank you everyone. I followed your advice and used vector<unsigned char> without the smart_ptr. Thanks to your suggestions it's working like a charm and I managed to fix some memory leaks coming from the previous management of m_dataBuffer.